# apply gdal to calculate raster that is already in qgis raster calculator

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator

I am using the following code in qgis to calculate some raster.It is not giving the correct result as it is in arcpy.I want to apply same in gdal.Can anyone help me how to use the gdal api.Please give me code

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
layer= iface.activeLayer()
entries = []
# Define band1
ent1= QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ent1.ref = 'boh@1'
ent1.raster = layer
ent1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( boh1 )

# Process calculation with input extent and resolution
calc = QgsRasterCalculator( 'boh@1 * 0.03705882+ 3.2', 
                            'D:\test\testtif', 
                            'GTiff',
                            layer.extent(), 
                            layer.width(), 
                            layer.height(), 
                            entries )

calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: I have closed this for now as it is nearly identical to your previous question.  The preferred protocol is to edit your original question, rather than to open an identical question.

Comment: Use [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html)